# Hide a video background comercial on mobile

Tags: css, video

So I don`t want to display the video background promo on mobile at all.
This is a full width screen video background.

My curent CSS is :

```
.video-section .pattern-overlay {
background-color: rgba(71, 71, 71, 0.59);
padding: 110px 0 32px;
min-height: 496px; 
   }
.video-section h1, .video-section h3{
text-align:center;
color:#fff;
}
.video-section h1{
font-size:110px;
font-family: 'Buenard', serif;
font-weight:bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin: 40px auto 0px;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
-webkit-text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
-moz-text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}
.video-section h3{
font-size: 25px;
font-weight:lighter;
margin: 0px auto 15px;
}
.video-section .buttonBar{display:none;}
.player {font-size: 1px;}
```

If anyone can help please give me a fix.

Thank you

Comment: Use media queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) in your css:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
 /*hide video background*/
}
```